# How to route traffic to website using a specified network connection on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, routing

I want to route all traffic to a website over my wireless connection while the rest of the traffic using my lan.  What I tried was first finding out the IP address of the website I want to go to.  For example, lets say pandora.com.  I found it resolves to 208.85.40.20.  I have entered that entry into my hosts file.  I then added that route using route add 208.85.40.20 mask 255.255.255.255 WirelessIP.  It doesn't seem to work however.  Instead of using the IP address, is there a way that I can just say.. this URL to route over that connection?  Does anyone know of a program that I can install that will do this.. possibly some sort of proxy or a software load balancer that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually.. what worked for me is:

```
route add qq.rr.ss.tt mask 255.255.255.255 WIRELESS_GATEWAY metric 1
```

Specifying the interface may have worked.. but it worked for me the way I specified above so no need to specify interface condition

Answer (score 0):

Your `route add` command should work. But, you'll probably need to specify the interface and metric options:

```
route add qq.rr.ss.tt mask 255.255.255.255 metric 1 if uu.vv.ww.xx
                                   a low metric --^    ^-- your wireless ip
```

If you don't specify the metric and the interface, Windows will figure out those values in such a way as to use your LAN connection.

Windows will use the route with the lowest metric value. Metric is assigned based on relative speed. The LAN will always have a lower metric because it's a "faster" connection (100 Mbps or 1000 Mbps) than the wireless (54 Mbps).