# 2 Internet Connections, 1 Computer. I feel this is harder than it should be

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, firewall

I have looked around for a while but haven't been able to find any answers, maybe because what I want to do isn't really possible, but that's why I am here.
Basically, I have 2 separate incoming internet connections.
Home wired ADSL line and a business 4G enterprise connection.The thing is, home connection has good ping, 16, but bad download, 4mbps, while the 4G has worse ping, 60, but much better download, ~30mbps. Also, being enterprise I am having trouble with certain P2P games due to firewall etc.
What I really want to do is set wifi (4G) to default for my PC so I can take advantage of the extra speed in normal use but use my wired connection (ADSL) for gaming so I can use open ports and have decent ping. In my mind I am thinking a rule along the line of "If outbound traffic is on port "game port" use Ethernet adapter" and then use wifi in all situations that don't match those rules.

edit: I am on Windows 10 and setting a metric seems to do nothing, it always defaults to ADSL for everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to route traffic to website using a specified network connection on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/65595/how-to-route-traffic-to-website-using-a-specified-network-connection-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

On certain firewalls (e.g. Fortinet's) what you need here is called "Policy based routing". Regular routing decides which gateway to use by looking at the destination address of traffic; the extension to destination port, source address or source port is covered by PBR.
Using 2 regular routes with different distances will not help; only one will be followed at any time.

One possible solution would be to get a router or firewall appliance which offers PBR; with, of course, at least 3 ports (internal, wan1, wan2).